# Manhwa where MC is the weak guy at an academy who goes out hunting for zombies and saves some of his teammates

Tags: story-identification, manga

Can someone please help me find the name of a manhwa?
Near the start of the manhwa MC is bullied by everyone in the academy for being weak, he gets some strength and against the recommendations of the instructor, goes hunting for mutated zombies with a group from an academy, and ends up saving some of the teammates.  Later he is hunting alone in a forbidden zone and while fighting a mutated panther, he is saved by a, I believe lvl 4 blonde girl with a katana. She is knocked of a cliff during the fight. The mc finds her and helps her. He has to carry her while trying to escape a team of bad guys. MC defeats the bad guys with some help from the girl.

When monsters are killed a crystal  can be collected, and people can get skill from cards.

Afterwards, the MC, having gotten stronger gets into trouble with a strong guy from the academy because the guy's little brother is a bully and while defending some weaker kid the MC beats the bully up. MC fights against the strong guy and the guy not accepting defeat takes a forbidden serum that hulks him out, but is still defeated and crippled by the MC. The bully's family is pissed and wants to kill the MC for "going too far", someone at the academy defends MC because the bully cheated taking the serum intending to kill MC.

Intending to kill MC the family has the academy send MC to raid a zone where strong monsters are and the hunter death rate is really high. MC is underestimated by the team of seasoned spec ops hunters but during the raid shows of his skills and saves the team. During the raid a group of assassins try and kill MC but are killed by MC and the team of spec ops hunters that now consider him a comrade and help him.

After returning to the academy he fights the bully again, bully having grown stronger. During the fight MC uses a muscle exploding punch type skill to ignore the bully's defense and destroying his arms. There we find out the reason the bully got so strong was because he had his arms surgically enhanced/replaced with metal/cyborg arms. The head of the family tries to kill MC but a strong old guy intervenes.

After the fight everyone is worried about the MC because the bulliy's family's intent on retribution. The spec ops hunter team invites MC to join them so the family cant touch him. The MC is also invited to attend a prestigious academy (same one the katana girl from the beginning was invited to).

MC decides to attend the academy.

On the way to the meet up place the MC encounters a high lvl martial artist that looks like a young girl and she helps and trains him. They reach a city where she buys the MC some skill cards and tells him to get his lvl evaluated. Evaluation goes well and she gives an extremely valuable and heavy spear that is made from a black meteorite. She parts ways with MC telling him to get stronger and to come find her in a floating city where only elite martial artists are allowed entrance.

MC is informed that he must travel through a dangerous territory to get go the academy testing place. On the way he encounters a guy that offers to guide him in exchange for the MC helping to get some sort of crystal from the bottom of a lake in order to cure a family member. MC accepts and after giving the guy the crystal goes on ahead by himself.

Fights a big worm in a desert area and finds a team of hunters. While walking with them, they fall into some sort of ancient ruins with forgotten technology. In the ruins they are attacked by strong monsters. At first they kill some but then they encounter some dangerous vines and a lot more monsters so they run. They eventually arrive at a central room where a bunch of hunters are fighting the source of the vines, a lvl 6 mutated monster. One of the hunters uses the others as cannon fodder in order to weaken the monster, intending to kill them and take the loot for himself. MC intervenes and kills him and the monster, retrieving the lvl 6 gem. Afterwards MC and survivors escape the ruins and part ways.

MC eventually gets to the academy meeting place and we find out that the team of hunters from before, are also academy examinees.

He also meets the katana blonde girl, from the beginning, again.

They take the test and pass. Some things happen and MC ends up sharing a house with the katana girl. Also while looking at all the loot he had acquired during his travels, he finds that the lvl 6 crystal he recently got, is somehow alive and enjoys eating other crystals.

That is what I can remember. Can anyone tell me what the manhwas name is?

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.